Want to understand the problem with this Remove Element Code?
I have coded to solve the problem in the leetcode but to some reason it is not accepted in the leetcode want to know what was the problem in the code as it is returning right output when running on the compiler.
Description:
Given an integer array nums and an integer val, remove all occurrences of val in nums in-place. The order of the elements may be changed. Then return the number of elements in nums which are not equal to val.
// Online Java Compiler
// Use this editor to write, compile and run your Java code online
import java.util.*;
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the size of the array");
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        int[] nums = new int[n];
        int k=0, val;
        System.out.println("Enter the elements");
        for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
            nums[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Enter the value to remove");
        val=sc.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<(nums.length);i++){
            if(nums[i]==val){
                nums[i]=nums[i]-val;
                k++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Here are number of elements left "+(nums.length-k)+" Numbers are deleted "+k);
    }
}

Example:
Enter the size of the array
4
Enter the elements
2
3
3
2
Enter the value to remove
2
Here are number of elements left 2 Numbers are deleted 2

I tried to solve the question based on the understand that we need to return the value of the elements which are not equal to the value which was asked to remove. I simply subtract it directly from the array itself. Although I have come to the solution by the help of youtube but want to learn the mistake I did in this.
But if I update the 'if' condition to this condition it is working in the leetcode
for (int i = 0; i < (nums.length); i++) {
        if (nums[i] != val) {
            nums[k] = nums[i];
            k++;
        }
    }


Welcome to SO. If you not did so already, please read [ask]. After this you might want to [edit] your question to add the following: 1) What is the task you're trying to solve? (Don't link but use text to describe the requirements), 2) Describe your approach to solve this as text (i.e. how you're thinking the algorithm should work), 3) If you can, provide examples of what doesn't work and what info you get on this.

One thing to note on Leetcode and other similar sites: they normally expect a very specific output format and often provide some framework code to achieve this. Any additional System.out.println() etc. may cause the tests to fail as the output doesn't match the expected format.

as stated above, leetcode usually doesn't expect you to print those. rather they expect a value to be returned. Can you share the link to that question?

Your code doesn't remove anything, but rather makes math subtractions on the elements. You can't remove elements from an array - only create a new one with fewer elements

If so, then int[] unique = IntStream.of(nums).distinct().toArray(); Sorted! (Well actually it might have been sorted to begin with)

Aman, there is absolutely no point discussing whether or not it works with us if we don't know the task definition (which you've been asked to provide)

@sittsering We only have return the value of k. The code I have shared is when I want to debug the problem.

@dragoness It is question number 26 Remove Element
leetcode explaination given in that question
Change the array nums such that the first k elements of nums contain the elements which are not equal to val. The remaining elements of nums are not important as well as the size of nums.

@g00se I don't want to increase the space complexity. I wanted to complete the question without using any other array. I'm aware that we can't alter the size of array after initialization.

Yes, now we know exactly the definition of the task, that is clear

@AmanSharma Leetcode question and what you are trying to do is different. The question is to remove duplicates from the sorted array while you are trying to remove elements from unsorted array which match the input value from user. I think you might not have understood the question properly.

We should not write a complete answer, otherwise we would interfere with the leetcode platform.
But I feel comfortable to give this hint.
You need to sort the array.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html
Arrays.sort(nums);


You do not absolutely need to sort the array.
